# sql syntax error for string value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to sql, and trying to figure out why I have a syntax error near the area it states. I don't seem to understand why my char(40) for Invoice.status is giving me question marks when comparing the string value.

ERROR:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
ear '?In Progress? AND Invoice.userId IN
                                (Select has_property.userId
                                ' at line 6
```

I am trying to find the userIDs of user who’s invoice is 'In Progress' and not in 'IN'

```
Select User.userId, User.email
From User
Where User.userId IN (
Select Invoice.userId
From Invoice 
Where Invoice.status = ‘In Progress’ AND Invoice.userId IN
                (Select has_property.userId
                From has_property
                Where has_property.property ID 
                NOT IN
                (Select has_property.propertyID
                From has_property, home_address
                Where  House.homeAddId = home_address.homeAddId And home_address.state = ‘IN’
                 )
                )
 );
```

---

I changed everything to proper single quotes, however I still get the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
ear 'userId = (Select Invoice.userIdFrom Invoice Where Invoice.status = 'In Progress'' at line 1
```

Comment: ‘In Progress’ => 'In Progress', ‘IN’ => 'IN'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the quotes you are using by single quotes `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't true single quotes, they're smart single quotes. You need this character: `'`, not `‘` and `’`.

So, instead of

```
Invoice.status = ‘In Progress’
```

use

```
Invoice.status = 'In Progress'
```